# How can i get rid of RETURN statement?

Tags: java, return

I do not need any return statement at the end. But otherwise it wont compile.

```
public class Word2 {

    private String word;

    public Word2(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getSubstrings() {
        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i+1));
        }

        return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: `public void getSubstrings()`

Comment: I'd recommend to do a little research before asking something. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I do not need any return statement at the end.

Actually if your `getSubstrings` method is declared as returning a `String` (as you have done) then you DO need a `return` statement.  The Java Language Specification says that you do.

If you aren't ever going to use the result, then you should declare the return type as `void` ... and you won't need a `return` statement.

```
    public void getSubstrings() {
        // no 'return' required
    }
```

However, now your method name is misleading.  It is conventional for a "get..." to return something.  That's what "getters" do.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you truly intend to do with your `getSubstrings` method. You declared it to return `String`, but that isn't actually your intention.

By convention, a `getX` method on a Java method returns the attribute `X` on the object, or something calculated from the object's attributes. Here, I would expect `getSubstrings` to return a `List<String>`, a list of the substrings, in which case your method should instead create a new `List<String>`, add the substrings to that list (instead of printing them), then return the list, like so:

```
public List<String> getSubstrings() {
    List<String> substrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        substrings.add(word.substring(0,i+1));
    }
    return substrings;
}
```

If, instead, you actually want to print the substrings to `System.out`, then you should give your method a more descriptive name like `printSubstrings`, and give it a `void` return type, which would declare that you don't return anything from the method.

```
public void printSubstrings()
{

    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(word.substring(0,i+1));
    }

}
```